# MDX calculated measure for dimension member

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, mdx, olap, dimension

I would like to create new measure called Efficiency that shows the value of non-ordered transactions to total value:

`Efficiency=[100%-(nonordered/total)]`

Unfortunately, my experience with MDX is rather short. I tried this code:

```
    CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Efficiency] 
AS 
IIF([Measures].[Offers Value]=0, 0
, WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Offers Value] AS
1- ([Measures].[Offers value], [Is Ordered].[Is Ordered - Status].&[0])
/ ([Measures].[Offers Value]))
,FORMAT_STRING="PERCENT",
, VISIBLE = 1;
```

Problems encounterd are:

1. `[Offers value]=0` or other error during calculation. Is there some solution like 'OnError' or 'IsError' in MDX?
2. `[Offers value]` is also a calculated measure. How can I decide to calculate [Offers value] prior to [Efficiency]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question: You would create two measures, and if you create `Offers value` first and position `Efficiency` after it in the calculation script, then you can just use the first one in the second.

You cannot use `WITH` in the calculation script, but only in `SELECT` statements. That is probably the reason why you get an error message (your first question).

Any your measure definition should probably look something like

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Efficiency] 
AS 
IIF([Measures].[Offers Value]=0, 0
, 1 - ([Measures].[Offers value], [Is Ordered].[Is Ordered - Status].&[0])
  / ([Measures].[Offers Value]))
,FORMAT_STRING="PERCENT",
, VISIBLE = 1;
```

just leaving away the `WITH ... AS`. You were close to it!

Comment: Whoa! Yes this is correct and works great. I've just changed `IIF([Measures].[Offers Value]=0, 0` to `IIF([Measures].[Offers Value]=0, NULL` as the zero value created zeros through all my time dimension. Now it is perfect. Thank you. It's a pity I cannot vote for answers to my own questions :[